# NVD3.js: Stacked and grouped bar chart with two y-axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using `NVD3.js` and want to create following chart:
[image]

As you can see - bars are *stacked*, *two axis* and **grouped** by x-axis

Using `multiChart` I got :

[image]

It is stacked, two axis, but **not grouped** by x-axis.

Maybe I need to use different chart type - not `multiChart`, but I didn't find bar charts where are two y-axis.

1) How can I achieve this using `NVD3.js`?

2) If it can not be done in `NVD3.js`, then which solution I can properly integrate?

Thanks!

Comment: NVD3 is a collection of common chart types implemented in D3.  If you want an uncommon chart type, like this one, you'll have to work with the D3 code yourself.  If you want to use the NVD3 style and other features, you can adapt their source code, but you'll need to get yourself to the point where you fully understand how to make both stacked and grouped bar charts in D3.  There are plenty of tutorials and examples you can explore to learn.

Comment: Sad to hear, but if there are no better answers, than create answer so the reputation (bounty) will not be wasted and I can accept your answer within 6 days.

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone else has a more creative option for adapting NVD3 -- or wants to go step-by-step explaining the basic d3 code!

Comment: As there is no help with my question and you are only one who joined discussion - please create answer, so I can accept it and the reputation is not lost.

Comment: I would strongly suggest dimple.js http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_grouped_stacked for more advanced usage.  If the example is not clear, I could create an example with your data.

Comment: It seems very nice, but I can not see line plus bar chart, or chart Where it is possible to combine different charts into one.

Comment: @timelyportfolio good example.  I'll remember to steer people towards dimple when they need more than NVD3.  @ Orbitum It looks like they have [detailed docs](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki), which might explain why we don't get many dimple.js questions here.  It seems to allow a lot more customization than NVD3, without requiring you to start from scratch -- but I would still advise going through basic d3 tutorials if you are going to be using any charting library built on d3.

Comment: This type of chart can be easily achieved with **c3js** and their `groups` option there. I was going to use c3js but then when I tested it on the production datasets it turned out that there are a lot of performance issues especially with bars chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NVD3 Javascript library is, to quote their website, "an attempt to build re-usable charts and chart components".  It's creators have made a couple key decisions in order to emphasize the reusability of the charts:

- They have focused on implementing standard chart designs (line graphs, bar graphs, scatterplots), but implemented in flexible, interactive ways.
- They have used the same data structure requirement for all the graphs:

  - The main data array contains multiple data series, each of which represents a logical grouping of the data;
  - Each series is an array of individual data objects containing two or more variables.
- All the graphs have a similar style and reuse important pieces of code.

The NVD3 library allows you to create a grouped bar chart *or* a stacked bar chart, and even [a chart that interactively animates between the two](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html).

Adapting that chart to create a stacked *and* grouped bar chart is not a simple task, in part because the data structure would be different.  You would need a three-level data structure (`series > sub-series > datapoints`, representing `groups > stacks > bars`) instead of the two-level (`series > datapoints`) structure used by NVD3.

All is not lost, however.  NVD3 is built on the [d3 Javascript library](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).  D3 is much more flexible and open-ended; it doesn't define specific chart types, it defines a way of manipulating a webpage to make it match your data. You can use it to create any type of chart that can be drawn with HTML or SVG.  But of course, that means that it is much more work, since you have to explicitly create all the parts of the graph, and make all the design decisions yourself!

I **strongly** recommend, if you want to use d3, start with the basics in the [tutorials list](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) or one of the [introductory books](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials#publications).  However, you'll also want to check out the [gallery of examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), and from there you'll find the following charts that will be of particular interest:

- [Mike Bostock's Stacked Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)
- [Bostock's Grouped Bar Chart of the same data](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)
- [Ali Gencay's adaptation of those examples to create a stacked, grouped bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518)

Once you have become familiar with building charts in d3, you may want to open up the NVD3 source code to see if you can borrow some of their reusable code components *(being sure to respect their [licence terms](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/LICENSE.md), of course)*.  However, I would not recommend doing so as a beginner -- it is a lot of code, and uses a lot of complex techniques to put all the pieces together.